# Open a dump PostgreSQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, dump

I have a `.sql` file and I wont just to access to the database.

I tried:

`mysql -u root -p<password> <database> < myFile.sql`

And I got an error:

```
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'PGDMP
```

I googled the issue and I found that it can be an encoding problem. So I looked at the output of the command

`> file myFile.sql`

Which gived:

> **myFile.sql: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0**

Here is my question, is that possible to open this database with `mysql-server` or `sqlite`? How?

Comment: Did you try it with ` --binary-mode` enabled, like the error message suggested?

Comment: You'll probably run into lots of oddball things migrating your database from Postgres to Mysql. When you `< yourdumpfile.sql` you are executing the SQL in that file in mysql database, not just "Opening the database".